# Is it possible to record a window without user intervention in recordrtc?

Tags: ffmpeg, recordrtc

I know it may sound shady, but I'm developing a window recording program (right now using ffmpeg + gdigrab to grab windows) that records 
The question is, can I pass the window to be recorded without the user having to choose it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome browser, you can open **Google Chrome Properties** dialog, find the **"Target"** box and put **`--enable-usermedia-screen-capturing`** at the end. E.g.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --enable-usermedia-screen-capturing
```

Now relaunch the Chrome browser.

Screenshot for chrome properties box:

[image]

Now try following code on any **HTTPs** page (or on localhost page):

```
var screen_constraints = {
    mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'screen'
    },
    optional: []
};

var hints = {
    audio: false,
    video: screen_constraints
};

navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(hints, function(screen) {
    // this is your screen; record it using MediaRecorder or RecordRTC
}, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Want to try on **HTTP** pages? Following flag may work:

```
--allow-http-screen-capture
```

Chrome flags reference: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/